# Thoroughly checking that the string entered is a URL

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I have this code so far, which will check if it has the http:// in front of it and if for example "google.co.uk" was entered, it would add http:// on in front of it.

However it doesn't get around when people put, say, "hello" it would then add http:// on front of it and count it as a URL. I need something that will check there is a suffix on the end aswell.

```
function checkURL($url) {

if (empty($url)) 

{
    return $url;


}
 else {

 if (preg_match('[a-z0-9-]i', $url)) {

    return $url;

    } else {

if (preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url)) {
return $url;

}
else { 

    $url = 'http://'.$url.'';
    return $url;
    }
```

}

And then another simple check once it's returned.

Please help!

Comment: Have you accounted for situations where the user enters a URL with a querystring?

Comment: Nope, why would that be a problem?

Comment: because by nature, link references end with TLD - .edu, .com, .org, etc., which is the suffix you are trying to validate; however, a querystring would throw a wrench in that logic, since it means the URL will not end with a TLD. As a result, you can check for the suffix, but it mustn't be at the end of the text. Alternatively, you can explode the text, using "?" as a delimiter, and you can then apply your logic. That should work also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't re-invent the wheel.

use this:

```
if (filter_var('someurl.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === true) {
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: Good call, I didn't know that option existed on filter_var.

Comment: @user1063679 filter validate url is a bit more complex than "only validates for http://" http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

A good regular expression for this was put out by [John Gruber here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: Can this be used in the preg_match function?